# Why does my signature revision number increment by 2 (in itext) after detached signing?

Tags: pdf, itext, digital-signature, acrobat

Having implemented a client-server signature webapp as explained in the B. Lowagie book :"Digital Sinatures for PDF document"(version : Signing a document on the server using a signature created on the client). 
I encounter this issue :
when I sign a pdf document (with preexisting empty signature field),the signature is valid (in adobe reader or in itext ), the affected revision of this signature is 1 but the total revision number changes from 0 to 2 (preventing the signature to cover the whole document).(In adobe reader, the document has only one revision)

Regards

David L.

Output of the verification tool (also present in the book)

===== systemed_certification =====

Signature covers whole document: false

Document revision: 1 of 2

Integrity check OK? true

Versions of itext : 5.5.6 and 5.5.9

[original](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2F03BFDA84B77A41!112&authkey=!AI52g6-K5cGFCYk&ithint=file%2Cpdf)
[signedresult](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2F03BFDA84B77A41!113&authkey=!ABPGZ7pxuxoE8A0&ithint=file%2Cpdf)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I cannot reproduce the issue with the sample result document `signedoutput.pdf` you provided. I get

```
Signature name: systemed_certification
Signature covers whole document: true
Document revision: 1 of 1
Subject: {SURNAME=[Leruse], C=[BE], CN=[David Leruse (Signature)], SN=[80110802537], GIVENNAME=[David Paul-Marie]}
Document verifies: true
```

using

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(resource);
AcroFields acroFields = reader.getAcroFields();

List<String> names = acroFields.getSignatureNames();
for (String name : names) {
   System.out.println("Signature name: " + name);
   System.out.println("Signature covers whole document: " + acroFields.signatureCoversWholeDocument(name));
   System.out.println("Document revision: " + acroFields.getRevision(name) + " of " + acroFields.getTotalRevisions());
   PdfPKCS7 pk = acroFields.verifySignature(name);
   System.out.println("Subject: " + CertificateInfo.getSubjectFields(pk.getSigningCertificate()));
   System.out.println("Document verifies: " + pk.verify());
}
```

*([VerifySignature.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/signature/VerifySignature.java#L115) test `testVerifySignedOutput`)*

Manual inspection of the PDF confirms that it definitively contains only a single revision.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help... i finally found the issue : it was between the client and the server...An extra feedline in the http post protocol made this extra revision.